# Javascript and html: button isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I am making a program that has an array of numbers and then the user inputs some values in and clicks on verify. the value he enters has to be in order with the array of numbers and if it isn't the user gets an alert message sorry HOWEVER the value inside the first input bar decides from which number of the array should the comparison should start. FOR example, if the array holds numbers like {2,4,6,8,10}
and the user enters 6 in the first input bar and then he enters 8 and 10 in the next two bars, he should get the result "678" HOWEVER if he doesn't get the first number right lets say he enters 3, and since 3 isn't in the array, then it doesn't matter what he enters in the other input bars, he would get the result "Sorry". similarly, if the user types 4 in the first input bar but then then in the second bar he types 8, he should still get the result "Sorry" since the order of the array is {4,6,8} not {4,8}.. Now, i made a program but the thing is, whenever i click on the verify button, nothing happens :/.. here are my codes. and here is also the result i am getting: https://jsfiddle.net/53j19rpt/

```
<html>

<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [];
    var t;
    var num = 2;
    var x = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        document.getElementById("one" + x);
    }

    function go() {
        for (var t = 0; t < 4; k++) {
            x[t] = num * (t + 1);
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (document.getElementById("one0").value >= x[k])
                if (document.getElementById("one" + k).value == x[k])
                    document.write(document.getElementById("one" + k).value);
                else
                    document.write("Sorry");
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <input id="one0" type="text">
    <input id="one1" type="text">
    <input id="one2" type="text">
    <input id="one3" type="text">
    <input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="go()">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
for (var t = 0; t < 4; k++) {
            x[t] = num * (t + 1);
        }
```

Code is going for an infinite loop here. the value of t is not getting incremented in the code.

Comment: I am still not getting any output

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here:

1. `x` first gets declared as an array (i.e. `var x = [];`, but then immediately     after that, x gets used as an iterator for the for loop (i.e. `for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {`). Later on in the start of function `go()`, when assigning values to `x`, it attempts to access `x[t]`, which does not work for an integer. So use a different variable in the iterator:

   `for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
       document.getElementById("one" + x);
   }`
2. In the second `for` loop, the variable `t` doesn't get incremented, which causes an **infinite loop**. Increment `t`, not `k`.

   `for (var t = 0; t < 4; t++) {`
3. The `if` statements have no braces, which causes only the next line to be executed... though the two `if` statements in sequence will still execute the statement after the second if when both conditions evaluate to *true*. If you need multiple lines of code after the `if` expression then wrap them in curly braces.

See the example below:

```js
var arr = [];
var t;
var num = 2;
var x = [];
for (var h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
  document.getElementById("one" + x);
}

function go() {
  for (var t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
    x[t] = num * (t + 1);
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    if (document.getElementById("one0").value >= x[k]) {
      if (document.getElementById("one" + k).value == x[k]) {
        document.write(document.getElementById("one" + k).value);
      }
      else {
        document.write("Sorry");
      }
    }//could have an else after this when one0's value is less than x[k]
  }
  console.log('done with function go()');
}
```

```html
<input id="one0" type="text">
<input id="one1" type="text">
<input id="one2" type="text">
<input id="one3" type="text">
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="go()">
```